# Make a pythonic one line statement like "return True if flag"?

Tags: python, syntax

Is there a way to write a one line python statement for

```
if flag:
   return True
```

Note that this can be semantically different from

```
return flag
```

In my case, None is expected to be returned otherwise.

I have tried with "return True if flag", which has syntactic error detected by my emacs.

Comment: I guess `if flag: return True` isn't what you want... It looks perfectly concise and clear to me.

Comment: What is expected return value if flag is falsy? `None`?

Comment: @utdemir I did not know yours works. Yes, That is clelar and concise. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a one line solution? Your two lines are perfectly readable. Does your text editor charge money for extra lines of code? ; )

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pythonic"? One line doesn't equal pythonic. E.g. try to understand what this does: `zip(*(iter(the_list),) * slice_size)`

Comment: @user5061 You are right in some sense.  I wanted one line *AND* pythonic. The title should be clear though.

Comment: @zell, are you returning nothing if the flag is a falsey value?

Comment: Yes, return None otherwise

Comment: @zell, how are you using the return value? `if flag: return True` is also a pep8 violation so not exactly pythonic

Comment: Just use this: `return (True if flag else None)` No more ugly inline if statements!

Comment: @JamesLu, how is that different to what has already been provided bar the unnecessary parens?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham A library code uses it, for info.

Comment: @zell, so the library tests for  None explicitly?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it's a ternary operator; not an if statement. It's an expression, not a command. It follows PEP 8, and does not require wrapping of if statements.

Comment: @JamesLu, have you seen my answer and the accepted?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh. Oops. When I saw it, there was no code block so I proceeded to write an answer.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding [what "pythonic" means](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). `Simple is better than complex.` and `Sparse is better than dense.` Thats the exact opposite of one-line in your case.

Comment: @user5061 Actually, two lines instead of one line does make your code more dense for a  monitor of small vertical size, thus potentially less readable.  Never mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return True if flag` doesn't work because you need to supply an explicit `else`. You could use:

```
return True if flag else None
```

to replicate the behaviour of your original if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
return bool(flag) or None
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bool `return bool(flag)` if you return False when the flag is a falsey value.

Or maybe the following depending on whether you return None:

```
 return True if flag else None
```

If you are testing the return value `if False` and `if True` will both evaluate to False so unless you are explicitly testing for None then `return bool(flag)` is sufficient.